# How can I base a .prettierignore file on .gitignore?

Tags: javascript, git, prettier

Looking at the Prettier docs, there is a tip to base your .prettierignore file on your .gitignore file.

[From the docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20230703224654/https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html):

> Tip! Base your .prettierignore on .gitignore and .eslintignore (if you have one).

Can someone explain what this means and how to do this? Is there a way to automatically add everything to your .prettierignore included in your .gitignore?

**Update 2023-09-05** Editing to highlight [@starball's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76608483/109538), where they note that `prettier` now respects `.gitignore` files by default.

Answer (score 37):

You can actually pass a flag to your prettier command `--ignore-path` and then give it the path of your `.gitignore` file so it will use that instead of the `.prettierignore` file.

```
prettier --ignore-path .gitignore
```

Comment: Shame that you can only give that option once (last one takes precedence): https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/8048 E.g. I have submodule which I need to ignore for prettier but cannot be in the .gitignore.

Comment: This solution may work for the command line, but this is usually not the best strategy (at least alone), because if you have a prettier IDE plugin, then that plugin will not know about the fact that you want to use .gitignore. (That is, unless you can configure your IDE's prettier plugin like shown in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode#prettier.ignorepath-default.prettierignore , but that is more work and may have complications, such as not working in an untrusted workspace).

Comment: I think the info here (including in the comments) will be outdated in Prettier 3.0. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76608483/11107541)

Answer (score 7):

They're not implying there's an automatic way to do this, but you could `cp .gitignore .prettierignore` (or copy it some other way, such as in your IDE). There is a [proposal to include other ignore files](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/8506#issuecomment-659604909) as well as a [node tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-sync?activeTab=readme) to automate this for you if you want to, though.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation being quoted in the question post is/was probably alluding to just copying the contents of your .gitignore and pasting it into your .prettierignore.

There's been other work on improving this for Prettier v3.0:

In Prettier 3.0, you can specify multiple ignore files on the commandline. See [Accept multiple --ignore-paths #14332](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/14332). Ex. `prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-path .prettierignore .` Actually you won't even need to do that, because...

In Prettier 3.0, .gitignore will be honoured by default. See [pull request: Ignore .gitignored files #14731](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/14731), follow up discussion in [Ignoring .gitignoreed files by default is overkill. #14831](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/14831).

If you're interested in the history of this, see these:

- [Proposal: Filter using ".gitignore" first, then ".prettierignore" second
  #8506](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/8506)
- [Multiple files for --ignore-path #8048](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/8048)
- [Ignore files that are not tracked by git (by default) #14115](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/14115)
- (in the VS Code extension GitHub) [Prettier ignore pattern as a vscode setting option #435](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/435)

Answer (score 4):

Don't copy the file, link it to your .gitignore so they keep in sync if you edit them in the future:

```bash
ln -s .gitignore .prettierignore
```

Comment: Doesn't that create a link with a full path? How is it going to work in a repository which is developed by a team?

Comment: @buraky: From what I see it seems to create a relative symlink, it doesn't include my full path. It works in our git setup.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell from reading the docs is they mean to have the same files in your `.prettierignore` as you do in your `.gitignore`, since anything in `.gitignore` won't be check into your repository anyway, not that you can point the `.prettierignore` to `.gitignore` and have it use that file, though that would be cool.  There's a similar issue raised and close [here](https://github.com/formium/tsdx/issues/517) that mentions using symlink since they use the same structure.